# Linking R packages during installation to a Linux RPM

Tags: linux, r, redhat, gmp

I have installed the rpm of GMP version 4.3.1 but when I try to download the
R package 'gmp' it fails with the following error saying that it cannot find
GMP.

*/checking for __gmpz_ui_sub in -lgmp... no
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see
http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package gmp*/

This verifies I have gmp installed
*/$ rpm -q gmp
gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64/*

Is there a command I can add to install.packages("gmp")  that will point to
the GMP rpm?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the exact same error as you when trying to install the R gmp package on Ubuntu, and it worked after installing libgmp3-dev. The equivalent rpm will be libgmp3-devel-something-or-other, try rpm search for your platform.